# An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, mysql, dependencies

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click
> menu or apt- get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message
> was: 'Error: Opening the cache (E:can not open /var/lib/apt/lists/
> repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease
> -fopen (13: Permission denied), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.)'. This usually means that your
> installed packages have unmet dependencies

I don't have a lot of experience using ubuntu.i am getting a red notification at the top.

Comment: `sudo rm -rf  /var/lib/apt/lists/ ` This will erase the information which packages are available for apt in your sources. `sudo apt update` will recreate it.

Comment: i did sudo apt update and red notification is gone for sometime and again same problem @nobody but why i am getting this error.

Comment: I do not know. but I think it has something to do packagekit (Or the backend). I never use it and I have never such Problem. I only use apt und update my system manually.